# Status bar turn to black when UINavigationController hides on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, xcode9

I use collectionView in my app and set status bar style to light and set `hidesBarsOnSwipe` of `navigationController` to true. But when I scroll cell up, navigationController is hides, but status bar turn to black color. and back to white when scroll collectionView to down. this is my code for navigationController:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    override open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    func transparentNavigation() {

        guard let pacificoFont = UIFont(name: "Pacifico", size: 20) else {return}

        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.foregroundColor, NSAttributedStringKey.font: pacificoFont]

        navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    }

}
```

Is there any way to repair this "feature"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43073806/3632832 would be helpful to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `translucent` Navigation bar, status bar gets its color from the Navigation bar. As a result when Navigation bar scrolls status bar falls to default black color.

If you want `translucent` Navigation bar and status bar to be of specific color (like white) you can use

You can add it in `ViewDidLoad`

```
    let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
    statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Hope this helps

Comment: no, it's not help. because I need status bar with transparent background. this solution add white background.

Comment: @jack-daniel : In `statusBar.backgroundColor =` specify the color you need buddy

Comment: I change color to UIColor.clear, but nothing. it changed from white to clear background, but the problem stayed the same.