# Status bar background colour issue happening in iOS 11.3

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, statusbar, iqkeyboardmanager

I have textfields in my viewcontroller view. So, few of textfields are hiding behind keyboard while appearing. So, I have integrated **IQKeyboardManager** by pod and textfields are moving up while keyboard appears.

But, strangely, I am facing some status bar issue after dismissing the keyboard.

Even I tried to changed the version too to **pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '6.0.2'** as per others suggestions to fix the issue, but, still its happening.

Any suggestions?

Before keyboard appearing

[image]

After keyboard disappears

[image]

Even I tried with following solution by adding in Appdelegate class, but, did not helped.

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.canAdjustAdditionalSafeAreaInsets = true
```

Comment: what issue you face for statusbar are its color or what , sorry image not clear

Comment: can you please share demo project with same issue?

Comment: Edit with clear image, please check.

Comment: we can not provide any solution direct to you. First we need to check in code thats why  i am asking to you for sample code so we can tried different solution.

Comment: What you want to know in sample project?

Comment: Im clearly telling, after keyboard disappears, statusbar going like above picture.

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish did able to get chance to check update images?

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper yes working on

Comment: Oh, Okay. Thanks

Comment: This has some issue with the library itself, even I am searching for a proper solution.

Comment: Still not found. If I got any solution will update. Thanks

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43073806/6786974) it may help you but without a detailed look in your code this cant be explained.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following configuration:

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.layoutIfNeededOnUpdate = true
```